# Application is getting crashed when using handler and thread to download an image

Tags: android, android-handler, java-threads

//This is my My MainActivity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ImageView mImageView=null,mImageView1=null;
ProgressDialog progressDialog=null;
ProgressDialog progressDialog1=null;

Handler handler=null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mImageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mImageView1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    progressDialog =new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog1 =new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog1.setMessage("Loading...");
    //progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

    handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if(msg.arg1==0){
            progressDialog.show();

            }else{
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }

            return false;
        }
    });


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Bitmap b = null,b1=null;
            /*runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            });*/
            Message mes=Message.obtain();
            mes.arg1=0;
            handler.sendMessage(mes);
            try {
                b = loadImageFromNetwork("http://www.gettyimages.in/gi- resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            final Bitmap finalB = b; final Bitmap finalB1 = b1;
            /*runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(finalB);
                }
            });*/
            mes.arg1=1;

            handler.sendMessage(mes);


        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    progressDialog1.show();
                }
            });
            Bitmap b = null,b1=null;
            try {

                b1=       loadImageFromNetwork("http://feelgrafix.com/data/wallpaper-hd/Wallpaper-HD-16.jpg");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final Bitmap finalB = b; final Bitmap finalB1 = b1;

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog1.dismiss();
                    mImageView1.setImageBitmap(finalB1);

                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private Bitmap loadImageFromNetwork(String url ) throws    MalformedURLException {
    Bitmap result= null;
    URL urlToRead=new URL(url);
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) urlToRead.openConnection();
        BitmapFactory.Options options= new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize=0;

        result=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream(),null, options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;

}
}
```

// This is activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    tools:context=".MainActivity">


android:id="@+id/textView" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>

// This is Manifest 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="appwidget.com.handlerexample" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Application is getting crashed immediately after launch . Please suggest what is going wrong in there.
I am trying to run this application and getting crashed. Unable to get log . Please suggest.

Comment: crash looks like NetworkOnMainThreadException ?

Comment: Got it solved by putting internet permission in Manisfest. Thanks.